# How to read multiple lines with more that one elements in a line from an array in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, split

Here is what i've done so far: but you should look at the print-screen to see what output i'm getting. and here is the elements in the .txt file that i trying to read from:

```
1000
1500 2
750
600
500 3
100
250
750
600 5
1500
400
500 4
1000
1500
750
-1
500
1500
```

just to let you know what this is, it is a Whammy game and the above numbers are the values that my spin() randomly pick from.

```
public class Board {

    ArrayList<Cell> cellList = new ArrayList<>(); // creating an arraylist that holds the array elemetns in it.

    public Board() throws FileNotFoundException {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("CellValues.txt");
        System.out.println("isFile: " + file.exists());

        try (java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(file)) {
            while(scan.hasNext()){

                String line = scan.nextLine();
                String[] lineArr = line.split(" ");
                System.out.println(lineArr.length); // test number number of index

                if(lineArr.length == 1){
                    int cellLine = Integer.parseInt(line);              // to be passd to Cell constructor
                    Cell cellObject = new Cell(cellLine);
                    cellList.add(cellObject);

                if(lineArr.length == 2){
                    int SpecialCell = Integer.parseInt(line);      // to be passed to Special Cell constructor
                    SpecialCell specialCellObject = new SpecialCell(cellLine, SpecialCell);
                    cellList.add(specialCellObject); 
                    //cellLine *= SpecialCell;
                    //int x = cellObject.getValue() * (int) specialCellObject.getMultiplier();
                }   
            }
        }
            for(Cell i : cellList){
            System.out.println(i); 
            }

            System.out.println("\ncurrent elements in the arraylist are: " + cellList.size());

            scan.close();
        }
    }
```

******** UPDATE according your advice with editing the IF **********

int cellLine = Integer.parseInt(line);  // to be passd to Cell constructor
                int SpecialCell = Integer.parseInt(line);      // to be passed to Special Cell constructor

```
            if(lineArr.length == 1 && lineArr.length == 2){
                Cell cellObject = new Cell(cellLine);
                SpecialCell specialCellObject = new SpecialCell(cellLine, SpecialCell);
                cellList.add(cellObject);
                cellList.add(specialCellObject);
```

Now i'm getting --> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1500 2"

Comment: Why can't you add the code here ?

Comment: just because the explanation i've annotated on the print-screen, but i'll post the code right up...

Comment: Use your IDE to automatically indent your code, and you should see one of the problems immediately. The second problem is that you're trying to parse a line containing two values as an integer. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JBNizet i swear to God, I agree with you, but i do not know why the professor is stating this in the assignment instructions !!! do you think there is any alternative way?

Comment: Well, we don't know the instructions. But I guess you must parse both numbers on the line. Since you just split that line to an array, this is quite easy, isn't it? Note that `if(lineArr.length == 1 && lineArr.length == 2)` doesn't make any sense. The length can't be equal to 1 and equal to 2 at the same time.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you so much for your hint, can you please give me an example of parsing two values on the same line. if you look at the elements in the main post, will see that i have lines with one elements and some lines with two, what indexes the elements with two values are gonna be. i actually don't know how to figure that out.

Comment: `int firstInt = Integer.parseInt(lineArr[0]); Integer secondInt = Integer.parseInt(lineArr[1]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want both values from the original line, right?  You need to use the individual strings that you split using `lines.split();`

And perhaps try the logic like this:

```
int firstValue = 0;      // initialize a first value (always used)
int secondValue = 0;     // initialize a second value (may or may not be used)

if(lineArr.length == 1){
        // parse just the first element. That's all we need.
        firstValue = Integer.parseInt(lineArr[0]);  
        // do stuff here...
}
if(lineArr.length == 2){
        // parse both elements.  We need both, right?
        firstValue = Integer.parseInt(lineArr[0]);
        lineArr[1] = lineArr[1].trim();  // remove any leading whitespaces!
        secondValue = Integer.parseInt(lineArr[1]);
        // do stuff here...
}
```

**EDIT**:

```
if(lineArr.length == 1){
        // parse just the first element. That's all we need.
        firstValue = Integer.parseInt(lineArr[0]);  
        // do stuff here...
}
if(lineArr.length > 1){
        firstValue = Integer.parseInt(lineArr[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < lineArr.length; ++i) {
            if (!lineArr[i].equals("")) {
                secondValue = Integer.parseInt(lineArr[i]);
            }
        }
        // do stuff here with firstValue and secondValue
}
```

Comment: Awe my gosh, i'm very thankful, it worked! now it's printing the first value of the element with two values but not the other value separated by the space, can figure out why?

Comment: `lines.split(" ");` will only find a second value if it finds exactly the delimiter you sent: `" "`.  So if there were multiple spaces it wouldn't work: `123<two spaces>456`, for example.  Fix this by adding `lineArr[1] = lineArr[1].trim();`

Comment: you have no idea how i'm appreciated to you, spent three nights on this. i'm trying to get the product of every two elements and if i had a problem will come to you, mentor :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the block beginning on line 33 will only execute should the array contain 1 element, which is exactly what you don't want it to do.  Move that block outside the first `if` block so that it can execute.  Better yet, do

```
if (lineArray.length == 1) {
    // code for one element here...
}
if (lineArray.length == 2) {
    // code for two elements here...
}
```

So specifically:

```
if(lineArr.length == 1){
    int cellLine = Integer.parseInt(line);              // to be passd to Cell constructor
    Cell cellObject = new Cell(cellLine);
    cellList.add(cellObject);
} 
if(lineArr.length == 2){  
    int SpecialCell = Integer.parseInt(line);      // to be passed to Special Cell constructor
    SpecialCell specialCellObject = new SpecialCell(cellLine, SpecialCell);
    cellList.add(specialCellObject); 
    //cellLine *= SpecialCell;
    //int x = cellObject.getValue() * (int) specialCellObject.getMultiplier();
}
```

Comment: when i do that, the cellLine within the second if cannot be accessed. notice that i'm passing it to the specialCellObject constructor.

Comment: The `else if` would seem to be unnecesssry since an array can only have a length of 1 or 2, but not both.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Right. Thanks!

Comment: @AhmedHadi It looks like you want the assignment `int cellLine = Integer.parseInt(line);` made regardless of whether or not `lineArray` is length 1 or 2.  So write it in both blocks, or write it before both blocks.

Comment: @AlessandroScarlatti i've tried that, but i get NumberFormatException: For input string: "1500 2"